# Setting up GRUB for multiple distributions on different storage devices

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, lubuntu, 18.04

In my laptop, I have a 128GB SSD (`/dev/sdb`) and a 1TB HDD (`/dev/sda`). Before today, I had Ubuntu 18.04 installed on a 30GB partition (`sdb5`) on the SSD alongside Windows 10 on a 90GB partition (`sdb3`).

Now I chose to install a minimal Lubuntu on the HDD for times when I just need to browse the web or do simple activities with minimal battery drain. I created an 7.5GB partition for / (`sda4`) as well as a 512MB swap partition (`sda3`) and a 5MB BIOS partition (`sda2`). The last one I made without really knowing what I was doing because otherwise I was getting a `partition table requires a separate partition for boot loader code` error. I left the biggest, `sda1` partition as my data partition for all systems.

After installation finished and the PC rebooted, I was greeted by my regular Ubuntu GRUB, located on the SSD from the previous Ubuntu install. Normally I'd be happy with that result - except this GRUB doesn't seem to see the Lubuntu partition. I checked GRUB Customizer and it doesn't show up there either.

My question is: How do I make the Ubuntu GRUB from the SSD see the Lubuntu on the HDD?

Comment: when you installed Lubuntu in sda4, you might have selected "Device for bootloader = sda" you already have your Windows 10 on sdb.. you have to select "Device for bootloader = sdb"

Comment: I left it on the default option, which was (I think) sda, indeed.

Comment: then, go to BIOS Settings and Choose sda as your first booting priority to boot to Lubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies to everyone who answered/commented... Before you had time to, I managed to try another fix that worked. Basically something that fixes most boot-related problems (I swear this software is magical), meaning I just ran `boot-repair` and voilà, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding "GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false" to your /etc/default/grub file and then do a "sudo update-grub".

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Add "GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false" without quotes if it's not there already and then:

```
sudo update-grub
```

It should scan for other partitions in other drives and add the entry to your grub.cfg