# How do I boot Windows 10 on a separate SSD with Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, uefi, ssd, windows-10

I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04 on a SSD dedicated totally to Ubuntu. It is installed in UEFI mode and has predefined (by me) root, efi, swap and home partitions.

I'm now planning to buy Windows 10 retail pack and install it on second SSD (or an m2), where Ubuntu will be my default OS to boot up. And I should get options on the boot screen where I can choose which OS to boot.

I want to add a third SSD which will be used as storage and can be used by both drive 1 and drive 2 for storage purposes.
How do I format the drives and all to achieve this?

My specs are Asus B250M-K with Intel Pentium G4560 processor. I believe retail versions of Windows are not motherboard bound, right?

---

**Update:**
I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on an SSD in uefi mode. I want to install Windows 10 on a separate SSD. Then I want to use both the drives, with Ubuntu drive being the primary (boots into Ubuntu if I don't choose anything else). So that I can choose which drive to boot. How do I accomplish this? I'm pretty sure my computer will be confused with two operating systems on two different drives.

Can I use burg to control the boot menu or does it only work when the operating systems are in the same drive?

My Google search gave nothing but dual boot articles in the same drive, not multiboot on different drives. A specific step-by-step answer would help.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048676/setting-up-grub-for-multiple-distributions-on-different-storage-devices?noredirect=1#comment1711611_1048676 this question may give you answer.

Comment: @PRATAP No, sorry. It doesn't really give me any direction to my question. Thank you for trying though.

Comment: you already have Ubuntu 16.04 on your SSD. say "sda". you will install Windows 10 in second SSD, say "sdb". and the third SSD you will use it for data. so grub has to see 1st SSD and 2nd SSD whether there are OS's..the above question and answer is of same kind.

Comment: Safest to disconnect all drives except Windows drive and install to that drive. Be sure to boot installer in UEFI mode as that will be how it installs. You may then have to use efibootmgr to reset UEFI boot order to Ubuntu first and maybe add it back into UEFI boot menu. UEFI often forgets entries when drive is disconnected. If using NTFS to share data, be sure Windows fast start up is off.

Comment: @PRATAP but it says nothing of the common efi partition. I made it only because I read it somewhere that if I use windows later in UEFI mode, windows may share that partition.  But I don't know how to do that and all.

Comment: You can can have one ESP per drive, and all do not have to boot from same ESP. You can manually copy /EFI/Windows or /EFI/ubuntu to other drive and use efibootmgr to change drive UEFI looks for boot entries. see `man efibootmgr`

Comment: @oldfred hi please, elaborate your process in an answer with steps what I should take. It will be much more understandable that way for me.

Comment: @Bluebug, in your case you are installing windows 10 in sdb which does not have anything to do with your sda and sdc. While you create windows in sdb.. Windows will make its own partitions like EFI, MSReserved, C Drive. Once windows10 is installed in sdb. grub in sda has to look for OS's in sdb. if you go through the above question link, it has the actual Question in its bottom.

Comment: Install Windows to separate drive and then if issues come back and post link to Boot-Repair Summary Report so we can make specific suggestions. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info  If you install Windows with other drive(s) connected it may not install where you want. It does not properly see Linux partitions and may cause issues.

Comment: @PRATAP Okay, I see. And what you suggest about the storage drive? Windows sure can't read EXT4.

Comment: there are some additional softwares to read ext4 in windows but i never prefer them as they make conflicts. Instead i always keep my data in NTFS formats. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWuTO.png please go through this pic.

Comment: @PRATAP I always used EXT4 as storage because I read it's much better than NTFS. But windows can hardly perform without NTFS.

Comment: So just to be sure, what you all are suggesting is that I install Windows normally and see. Right?

Comment: you are very safe to proceed as you are installing Windows in brand new SSD. which does not have anything to do with other devices. like sda & sdc.